# AWS SSM : Pass tag-name instead of Instance-ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am working on AWS, where we have instances running SSM client. For automation, I am passing certain commands to these instances time-to-time. Currently, I have them setup with instance-id. This is proving inflexible for us, since any change to instance-id, will force me to update repository-code, and it's a hardcoded value.

How can I replace instance-id with tag:Name or similar.

Current code :

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids 'i-12434546' --region 'eu-central-1' --document-name 'AWS-RunShellScript' --comment 'Restart Pod' --parameters commands='sudo -u ubuntu kubectl rollout restart deployment.v1.apps/supplier-service-deployment' --output text
```

I want to replace

```
--instance-ids 'i-12434546'
```

With tag:Name. Any help would be nice. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is provided directly on the documentation page (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html)

> To target a larger number of instances, or if you prefer not to list individual instance IDs, we recommend using the Targets option instead. Using Targets , which accepts tag key-value pairs to identify the instances to send commands to, you can a send command to tens, hundreds, or thousands of instances at once.

You can use `--targets` option instead of `--instance-ids`:

```
aws ssm send-command \
--targets Key=tag:tag-name,Values=tag-value \
[...]
```